# Show Form before Application.Run

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a static method that shows a form as dialog. And that method can be called from anywhere of the application, like from a normal thread, from a UI thread. Its calls are located everywhere. One more thing this method does is that it doesn't blocks the call even its further calling `ShowDialog()` of the `Form`. So finally I got the following code working.

```
   public static void Method()
   {        // doesn't block the call
            ThreadStart threadStrart = delegate
            {
               DialogResult result = new FormTest().ShowDialog();
               //further code removed
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadStrart) { IsBackground = false };
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
    }
```

Everything works fine and as expected. But problem occurs when this method is called before `Application.Run`. Then it never shows up until `Application.Run` is called. However its possible in design that application may get exit/closed without even calling `Application.Run`. So in that case, user will never see the Form.

PS : That form is not main form.

Comment: How are you waiting without `Application.Run()`?

Comment: In a loop and some other things needs to be done before `Application.Run`.

Comment: It is a Z-order problem.  A dialog needs an owner, yours doesn't have one because it is running on a worker thread.  So it has the desktop window as the owner.  The window you create in your main thread will overlap it.  Not the only problem, you'll also get to debug [this nasty issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant : What would you advise other than that ?

Comment: How are we supposed to guess *why* you are doing this?

Comment: As written in question, I need to show the form from a normal thread or from a UI thread without blocking the call. Thats the whole reason I came up with the method. :)

Comment: You didn't answer the question.   What does the form do?

Comment: Gets user feedback, and submits to server. Is that really necessary to know ?

Comment: It is not generally possible to show any Form before the application has started running. I believe that you may be confused about how a standard WinForms application works. If you are getting user feedback, then your application has already begun, even if it never hits the "main" form.

Comment: Yes but problem is. Application may reject current user before even calling `Application.Run`. Things needs to be done before Application.Run and if those things fails, the app needs to show the form or maybe the main form later on. Too many scenarios in there, It truly became very confusing. :) Anyways, thank you everyone for all your efforts :)